# Add Windows partition to grub2 boot loader in CentOS 7

Tags: windows-7, boot, centos, multi-boot, grub2

I had Windows 7 installed on my laptop. Then I installed CentOS 7. Installation completed successfully, but when I reboot I can see only CentOS and CentOS recovery. I did not see the Windows partition. After logging into CentOS, I can go to the Windows partition. NTFS drives are working fine.

But how do I add a Windows partition to grub?conf file.
My Windows partition is /dev/sda1.

What could be the issue for not recognizing the Windows partition ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I know this is a little late but:

1. Make sure ntfs-3g is installed so that CentOS 7 can identify windows drives

Depending on the time you read this you may have to enable the RPMFORGE repo.

Code to enable RPMFORGE Repository (run as root):

```
rpm --import http://apt.sw.be/RPM-GPG-KEY.dag.txt;
rpm -Uvh http://pkgs.repoforge.org/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.5.3-1.el6.rf.x86_64.rpm;
yum install ntfs-3g -y
```

2. Next run grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg to add the Windows 7 partition to the grub2 menu

Profit!

Comment: i tried installing ntfs-3g on centos and done changes in grub file and ended up corrupting grub. So i reinstalled windows and using centos in VM after 2 days of posing this question. 
Thanks for reply. I will try this in VM and test it again.

Comment: I was actually surprised that any of this needed to happen post install. In my experience with earlier CentOS I recall the standard grub options being created and then an other option (which was my windows install) being created. With the advance to grub2 I figured this would be automated better.